# Show that $K(\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1})$ is a degree $4$ Abelian extension of $K=\Bbb Q (i\sqrt{14})$

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I have to show that $K(\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1})$ is a a degree $4$ Abelian extension of $K=\Bbb Q (i\sqrt{14})$.

Now, $a=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1}$ has minimal polynomial $f(x)=x^4+2x^2-7$ over $\Bbb Q$, which can be checked. I have to show that that $f$ is irreducible over $K$ and that the extension is normal. Then it'll follow that it's Galois and hence Abelian since it has degree 4. WolframAlpha tells me that the roots are $\pm \sqrt{2\sqrt2-1},\pm i\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+1}$. So, the field is also normal as $\alpha \in L \implies \sqrt{2} \in L$ and then $i\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+1} = {i\sqrt{14} \over \sqrt{2} \alpha} \in L$.

Then the only thing left to prove is that $f$ is irreducible over $K$. Please help me out.

**EDIT :** Writing $K_1=K(\sqrt{2})$, we get that $[K_1:K]=2$ as otherwise $K_1=K$ and $[\Bbb Q{\sqrt{2}}:\Bbb Q]=2=[K:\Bbb Q]$ mean $K=\Bbb Q{\sqrt{2}}$ but that's absurd as $\Bbb Q{\sqrt{2}}$ is real while $K$ is not. So, we'll be done if we can prove that $[L:K_1]=2$. The obvious choice for minimal polynomial is $x^2+1-2\sqrt{2}$ and it'll be enough if we can show that it is indeed irreducible over $K_1$.

Comment: HINT.-$x_0\in K\iff x=a+b\sqrt{-14}$ and $f(x_0)=(a^4-84a^2b^2+196b^4+2a^2-28b^2-7)+i4\sqrt{14}ab(a^2+1-4b^2)$ from which it is impossible that $f(x_0)=0$. Then $f(x)$ has neither a linear factor over $K$ nor a cubic factor. It remains to prove that $f(x)$ it is not a product of two quadratic factor over $K$.

We have that the corresponding splitting polynomial over $\mathbb C$ is $f(x)=(x-\sqrt{1+2\sqrt 2})(x+\sqrt{1+2\sqrt 2})(x-i\sqrt{-1+2\sqrt 2})(x-i\sqrt{-1+2\sqrt 2})$

Can you finish now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found that $[\Bbb{Q}(a):\Bbb{Q}]=4$. Because $K$ is Galois over $\Bbb{Q}$, we have${}^1$
$$[K(a):K]<4\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad[\Bbb{Q}(a)\cap K:\Bbb{Q}]>1,$$
which is of course equivalent to $K\subset\Bbb{Q}(a)$. Now it suffices to check that $\sqrt{-14}\notin\Bbb{Q}(a)$.

---

1: It is very much worth while trying to prove a general version of this equivalence; draw a diagram and try to prove when exactly the degree of a compositum of fields is precisely the product of their degrees. See also corollary 3.19 on page 41 of [Milne's notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf), and the diagram there.

Comment: Why is $\Bbb Q(a)$ Galois over $\Bbb Q$? It looks to me that $\Bbb Q(a)$ has two real embeddings and two (conjugate) complex embeddings, thus cannot be Galois over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @WhatsUp You are right; I meant to write $K$. Corrected now.

Comment: I knew this result, but was overly complicating everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}-1}, b=i\sqrt{14}$ and then we know that $[\mathbb{Q} (a) :\mathbb{Q}] = 4$ and $[\mathbb{Q} (b) :\mathbb {Q}] = 2$.

If we assume that these fields are subfields of $\mathbb {C} $ then we can observe that $b\notin \mathbb{Q} (a) $ and hence $[\mathbb{Q} (a, b) :\mathbb {Q} (a)] =2$ so that $[\mathbb{Q} (a, b) :\mathbb{Q}] =8$ and thus $[\mathbb{Q} (a, b) :\mathbb{Q} (b)] =4$ and we are done.